# QState invokeMethodOnEntry error

Tags: qt, methods, state

I've implemented a state machine by using Qt 5.2 with no problems. Now I want to invoke a slot when I'm in a particular state by the command:

```
s2->invokeMethodOnEntry(&label, "showMaximized");
```

but when I compile my code the following error appears:

error: 'class QState' has no member named 'invokeMethodOnEntry'

Is there another method that has the same function? I'm not able to find it.
Thanks a lot

Luca

Comment: You mean [this](http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtanimationframework/qtactionstate.html#invokeMethodOnEntry)? In short, it is QtActionState, not QState.

Comment: I don't have QtACtionState lib in my qt library, so I can't use it... I only have QState. Should I have it? in which folder? tks

Comment: what's the difference between QState and QtActionState... they come from different qt framework?

Comment: `QtActionState` was part of an experimental version of the Qt Animation Framework - part of the Qt 4 core module. This was before the state machine and animation frameworks became finalized. You're using some outdated documentation, because the method you refer to has not been around for ~4 years now. What Qt version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There's no `invokeMethodOnEntry` in the public Qt 5 API. There used to be in an experimental version of `Qt Animation Framework` in Qt 4, but it doesn't even exist in the latest Qt 4 version. Where did you get your outdated Qt documentation?

If you wish to run some code on entry to a state, there are three ways to do it:

1. Connect a slot to the state's `entered` signal - you're lucky since `showMaximized` is a slot:

   ```
   connect(s2, SIGNAL(entered()), label, SLOT(showMaximized()));`
   ```
2. Connect a lambda functor to the state's `entered` signal:

   ```
   QPointer<QLabel> labelPtr(&label);
   connect(s2, &QAbstractState::entered, [=labelPtr]{
     labelPtr->showMaximized();
   });
   ```
3. Subclass the state and reimplement the `onEntry` method.

Comment: Thank you Kuba, you really helped me, it's nowall clear to me. I thought Qt Animation Framework was also present in Qt 5. I's like to ask you two other questions: 1) How can I check the current state of the machine? 2) Can I add transition between two states without setting sender and recevier? thanks a lot for your help. Luca

Comment: @lukigno Sure, the animation framework is included, but the documentation you were looking at was not for a released version, but for an interim, experimental variant that was obsoleted rather quickly. Don't use 4+ year old documentation and you'll be fine :)